# zfs send to NAS with PIGZ compression slowness

Tags: zfs, compression, qnap, solaris-11

The following command that I use to backup used to take 5 minutes to complete and since last week it is taking around 25 minutes. This is after restarting a switch stack the server is connected to. The NAS 192.6.222.116 is in a different subnet to the server. How should I go about troubleshooting this issue?

```
zfs send -Rv shares1-pool/homedir@Cron-Snap-OraZ-Mon-030723 | pigz > /NAS/test/archive_shares1.gz
```

The server is not struggling for memory,

```
root@mars:~# echo ::memstat|mdb -k
Page Summary                            Pages             Bytes  %Tot
---------------------------- ----------------  ----------------  ----
Kernel                                 724362              5.5G    9%
Defdump prealloc                       173879              1.3G    2%
ZFS                                    912162              6.9G   11%
Anon                                  1282098              9.7G   16%
Exec and libs                           44767            349.7M    1%
Page cache                             986194              7.5G   12%
OSM                                   1792000             13.6G   22%
Free (cachelist)                       469418              3.5G    6%
Free (freelist)                       1774352             13.5G   22%
Total                                 8159232             62.2G
```

iostat,

```
         cpu
     us sy st id
     13  4  0 84

                    extended device statistics
    r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
    0.0    0.4    0.0    0.8  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.1   0   0 sd3
    0.2    0.4    0.8    0.8  0.0  0.0    0.0    3.2   0   0 sd5
    0.4   48.4   51.2 1507.4  0.0  0.1    0.0    1.5   0   1 ssd11
    0.0   49.2    0.0 1507.4  0.0  0.1    0.0    1.6   0   1 ssd12
    0.0   23.4    0.0  729.6  0.0  0.0    0.0    1.3   0   1 ssd13
    0.0   23.0    0.0  729.6  0.0  0.0    0.0    1.1   0   1 ssd14
   50.8   15.8 5527.4  108.8  0.0  0.3    0.0    4.3   0  24 ssd15
   53.4   16.2 4624.1  108.8  0.0  0.3    0.0    4.7   0  24 ssd16
    0.0   15.6    0.0  177.8  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.9   0   0 ssd19
    0.0   15.8    0.0  177.8  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.9   0   0 ssd20
   39.2   58.8  320.6 1293.5  0.0  0.2    0.0    1.8   0   6 ssd21
   48.8   57.0  334.9 1293.5  0.0  0.2    0.0    2.2   0   7 ssd22
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 st2
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 st3
    0.0  305.2    0.0 9766.4  7.0 10.0   22.9   32.8 100 100 192.6.222.116:/nfs_share
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 192.6.223.116:/nfs_share
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 192.6.224.40:/nfs_share
```

dlstat

```
  LINK    IPKTS   RBYTES    OPKTS   OBYTES
   net0   50.82G    9.10T   39.06G  134.91T
```

vmstat

```
 kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
 r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr s3 s5 sd sd   in   sy   cs us sy id
 0 0 0 32028280 10823336 589 877 3469 0 0 0 0 7 7 40 40 13788 14114 9252 6 2 91
```

mpstat

```
 CPU minf mjf xcal  intr ithr  csw icsw migr smtx  srw syscl  usr sys  st idl
   0   72  10  439  1053  370  920   55   60  114    0  1207    6   2   0  93
   1  159  18 1190  2957 2276 1362   42   87  130    0  2185    7   3   0  90
   2  110  19  512  1045  287 1401   56   86  135    0  2209    7   2   0  91
   3   97  10  370   571   45  946   53   61  116    0  1362    6   2   0  92
   4   73   9  450   929  437  904   52   59  115    0  1201    6   2   0  93
   5  158  19  536  2706 1933 1411   50   88  134    0  2375    7   3   0  90
   6  110  16 1137  2476 1821 1349   57   84  132    0  2236    7   3   0  90
   7   97   9  373  2050 1518  959   54   61  115    0  1339    6   2   0  92
```

On the NAS, there isn't any errors/warnings and seems to have enough space available for the backup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of performance do you get if you send it to another NAS system?  Or to a local file?

Comment: I would check the bandwidth between the source server and your NAS with something as `iperf`

Comment: @AndrewHenle I get the same slow performance with a different NAS on a different subnet. When I do it locally, it is performing as fast as it used to do with the NAS.